# chromedriver 116.0.5845.96 cannot set profile

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I use latest chromedriver 116.0.5845.96. When I open page with specified profile I obtain error:

unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Before the upgrade it worked correctly.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument($"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options))
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

    //....
}
```

Comment: --no-sandbox argument does not help